# Как отображать содержимое модального окна на больших экранах?

Tags: modal, bootstrap5

Что за чушь я написал в вопросе, но попробую объяснить)

Как в бутстрапе реализовать модальное окно по нажатию кнопки на маленьких экранах и игнорировать это модальное окно на больших дисплеях?

Есть фильтр товаров. Он всегда отображается на больших экранах. Но на маленьких экранах контент должен быть помещен в модальное окно и скрыт. И появляется только по нажатию кнопки.

Я не мог найти другого решения, кроме как дублировать контент и скрывать один контент на маленьких экранах, а другой контент на больших экранах. Но это, конечно, неправильно.

Возможно есть другое решение - с удовольствием прислушаюсь к вашему совету.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    <i class="bi bi-funnel"></i>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="X"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Весь код, кроме контента, должен быть скрыт на больших экранах.